# Finding element across dictionaries - C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

The input data is shown below:

[image]

As you can see, at `1/1/2017`, injector I1 is connected to four wellbores with some factors.. At date `1/2/2017`, I1 is connected to three wellbores with respective factors.

I need to get pattern factor values at a particular date. For example `1/1/2017`, 
when the user mentions I1 and P2 for example.

The way I thought it might work is by using Dictionaries such that First dictionary as:

- `key`: `Date`
- `value`: `Dictionary<injector,list<wellbores>>`

and another dictionary as:

- `key: Date`
- `value`: `Dictionary<injector,list<factors>>`

How do I populate the respective dictionaries and access data for let's say 
date: `1/1/2017`   and injector - wellbore combination of i1-p2 .
Am i using the right approach?

The table structure or input data is how it is presented. There is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Where is your data located?  In a database a DataTable or ?

Comment: it's in the database but I can extract it as lists if required. @SiamakFerdos

Comment: I think it's best approach you create a model then extract data as a list of this model. Then do a Linq on it as you want.

Comment: okay! can u give a brief example? @SiamakFerdos that would really help me to move forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can fetch the data as a list and the user inputs `Injector` and `Wellbore` value, why don't you just use LINQ to get your desired object. The way I would have implemented it as  -

```
public class Data {
     public string Injector {get;set;}
     public string Wellbore {get;set;}
     public DateTime Date   {get;set;}
     public double Factor   {get;set;}
}
```

Then  load the items into the list (`Using NHibernate or EntityFramework or plain old ADO.Net wrapper class to read DataTable and load into a list.`) -

```
var itemList = .....load items from database in list of type `List<Data>`.
```

If user supplied value is `I1` and `P1`, then -

```
var item = itemList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Injector == I1 && x.Wellbore == P1);
```

Now `item.Factor` is the factor I am looking for.

Comment: can I add "date" also as a condition here? at what date is also important

Answer (score 1):

I would use Dictionary

but you can read your values by your key 
I would give a generic example

Use would be like this

you can use what ever type

```
int myValue1 = GetValue<int>("your key", your Dictionary);
bool myValue2 = GetValue<bool>("your key", your Dictionary);
string myValue3 = GetValue("your key", your Dictionary);


  public static T GetValue<T>(String paramName, Dictionary<string, string> param = null) where T : new()
        {
            Type myTypeObj = null;
            T MyT = new T();
            if (MyT == null)
            {
                myTypeObj = typeof(T);
                myTypeObj = myTypeObj.GetProperty("Value").PropertyType;
            }
            else
            {
                myTypeObj = MyT.GetType();
            }

            MethodInfo myMethodInfo = myTypeObj.GetMethod("Parse", new[] { typeof(string) });
            string value = "";
            if (param.ContainsKey(paramName))
            {
                value = param[paramName];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    object[] reflParm = { value };
                    return (T)myMethodInfo.Invoke(MyT, reflParm);
                }
            }
            return default(T);
        }

        public static String GetValue(String paramName, Dictionary<string, string> param = null)
        {
            string value = "";
            if (param.ContainsKey(paramName))
            {
                value = param[paramName];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                    return value;
            }
            return String.Empty;
        }
```

in your case you should return your list by key and then you will get your list then you can do whatever you want with it

I hope that i could help